# When using Authorize.net's DPM method, I can only get a cryptic error message

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, authorize.net, drupal-commerce

I have a simple checkout form and I'm using Authorize.net's DPM (Direct Post Method) and I keep getting this error message:

`An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.`

```
  This transaction has been approved.
```

It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.

Any ideas on what might have caused this error? Authroize.net's support had 0 helpful information and they don't store failed API responses.

thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are running your website on HTTPS not on HTTP.
That was my case and resolved it by updating SSL.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Authorize.Net is trying to contact your server and is unsuccessful. The transaction is approved but they cannot send the user back to your website like you want them to.

Their article [Relay Response Basics and Troubleshooting](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536) covers this issue in great detail.